# How may I count the number of words in a paragraph? I keep miscounting

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to code a program that count the number of letters, words, and sentences in a text. I may assume that a letter is any lowercase character from a to z or any uppercase character from A to Z, any sequence of characters separated by spaces should count as a word, and that any occurrence of a period, exclamation point, or question mark indicates the end of a sentence.

So far, I could count both the number of letters and sentences correctly, but I miss out on the number of words:

e.g.
yes!

The output should be:
3 letter(s)
1 word(s)
1 sentence(s)

What I get is:
3 letter(s)
0 word(s)
1 sentence(s)

UPDATE: It works fine now after typing out another (words++) in the end right before the printf function. Thanks for the help guys :).

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Enter text: ");
    printf("Output:\n");
    int lettercount;
    int words = 0;
    int sentences = 0;
    int letters = 0;
    int length = strlen(text);
    for(lettercount = 0; lettercount < length; lettercount++)
    {
        if(isalpha(text[lettercount]))
        {
            letters++;
        }
        else if(text[lettercount] == ' ' || text[lettercount] == '\t' || text[lettercount] == '\n' || text[lettercount] == '\0')
        {
            words++;
        }
        else if(text[lettercount] == '.' || text[lettercount] == '!' || text[lettercount] == '?')
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    words++;
    printf("%i letter(s)\n", letters);
    printf("%i word(s)\n", words);
    printf("%i sentence(s)\n", sentences);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested and debugged with shorter sentences? Reduce the test data to be as simple as possible and that still reproduces the problem (e.g two words). Then use a debugger and/or debug print statements to trace the program execution.

Comment: Hint: `text[lettercount] == '\0'` is always false. Also hint: `strlen` is O(n) in the length of the string, don't call it each time through your loop.

Comment: I think your problem can be reproduced even with a single word sentence like: `Yes!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always have words -1 because you only add new word to your counter after space or new line but what about the last word !? always the last word will not be counted so after counting any paragraph add 1 to your word counter ..
Ex : Yes! --> 3 letters 1 Sentence 0 word ! so you add one and solved
another Ex : Hello World! --> 10 letters 1 sentence 1 word ! adding one and it's solved

Comment: Thank you, Omar! I just wrote another words++ right before the printf in the end, and it fixed it :).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is that it does not count any 'final' word in your input text if that does not have a space after it (the terminating `'\0'` character will *not* be part of the tested string, as the `strlen` function does not include that.

Further, you will have problems if you have words that are separated by more than one space; to address this, you could use an `inWord` flag to keep track of if the current character is already inside a word and, if not, set that flag whenever we find a letter.

Also, your sentence count will be problematical if you have things like `"..."` in your input; the commented-out line after your `sentences++;` line will fix that (if you want to).

And, finally, just to be precise, you should not assume that the letters "a" thru "z" and "A" thru "Z" will be in a continuous sequence. They *probably* will be (most systems these days use ASCII encoding) but you should use the `isalpha` function for more portability (and the `isspace` function, too).

```c
int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Enter text: ");
    printf("Output:\n");
    int lettercount;
    int words = 0;
    int sentences = 0;
    int letters = 0;
    int inWord = 0;// Set to 1 if we are inside a (new) word!
    int length = (int)(strlen(text)); // Don't evaluate length on each loop!
    for (lettercount = 0; lettercount < length; lettercount++) {
        int testChar = text[lettercount]; // Get a local copy of the current character
        if (isalpha(testChar)) { // Don't assume that 'a' ... 'z' and 'A' ... 'Z' are in contiguous sequences
            letters++;
            if (!inWord) words++; // Any letter means that we're in a (possibly new) word...
            inWord = 1;           // ... but now set this 'flag' so as not to count others!
        }
        else if (testChar == '.' || testChar == '!' || testChar == '?') {
            sentences++;
        //  if (inWord) sentences++; // Check that we're in a word, or stuff like "..." will be wrong
            inWord = 0; // Now we are no longer inside our current word
        }
        else if (isspace(testChar)) { // We could also just assume ANY other character is a non-word
            inWord = 0; // Now we are no longer inside our current word
        }
    }
    printf("%i letter(s)\n", letters);
    printf("%i word(s)\n", words);
    printf("%i sentence(s)\n", sentences);
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Also, your method could readily be extended to handle more options. For example, what to do with numerical digits? And how to handle hyphenated words: will "self-effacing" count as one or two words?

Comment: Adrian, thank you so much for your assistance! Haha I am super newbie to coding. I am doing CS50 Introduction to Computer Science as my first course. I am currently on week two, so it's really difficult for me to grasp all these concepts at once.
I wonder if you could explain inWord and (!inWord) more? What does the exclamation mark stands for?
Thank you again.

Comment: @Bryce The `inWord` variable keeps track of whether or not our current position is *already* inside a word; if it is zero (which is what the `!inWord` tests for - that would perhaps have been clearer if I had used `if (inWord == 0)`), we have found the start of a new word, so we set that flag to 1 (so we don't keep incrementing our word count until we find a non-letter, when we set it back to zero). Hope this helps.